# How to call component function from iframe using angular 4

Tags: angular, iframe

I am using to display the iframe in angular4 application i.e in localhost:4201.  iframe page is from localhost:9000. In my iframe page there is one button. if i click the button, need to execute my angular4 component function. I tried this one, but it throws error

**localhost:9000 - index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sampleMyHtmlApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 20px 0px;">
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Account Number</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAccountNo" placeholder="Account number">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick='parent.SampleFunction()'>Action</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**localhost:4201**

**app.component.html**

```
<iframe width="100%" [src]="url | safe" style="height: 302px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
     ....
})

export class appComponent {

    private url: string = "http://localhost:9000";

    constructor() {
        (<any>window).SampleFunction = this.SampleFunction.bind(this);
    }


    SampleFunction() {
        console.log('SampleFunction');
    }

}
```

when i click this, its shows error like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried postMessage?

Comment: @yurzui i didn't ever tried that one. i don't know how to use that

Comment: in addition to @yurzui answer: You can send messages between main window and Iframe window. So post message to main window and on message call needed procedure. This is a small example: https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Comment: @Chandru did you solve it?

Comment: @Manoj Yes!. I solved it and posted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!. I did solve the problem send or receive data using angular-4 and iframe.

example :-

**app.component.html**

```
<iframe width="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="url | safe" style="height: 500px; border: none;" (load)="onLoad()" #TheIframe></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('TheIframe') TheIframeEl: any;

    constructor() {
        (<any>window).reciveDataFromIframe = this.reciveDataFromIframe.bind(this);
    }

    onLoad() {
        const object = {
            'message': "Hello World!"
        };
        this.TheIframeEl.nativeElement.contentWindow.postMessage(object, 'http://localhost:3001');
    }

    @HostListener("window:message", ["$event"])
    reciveDataFromIframe(event: MessageEvent) {
        this.load(event.data);
    }

    load(data) {
        console.log('data', data);
    }
}
```

[Reference send and receive data using iframe](https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299)